# Checkout not working in Magento 1.9.0.1 patched

Tags: checkout, error, ce-1.9.0.1, patches, supee-6788

In the last step of the onepage checkout the order is not placed. 
An error alert appears instead. I presume it's related to one of the patches released in the last months, the problem has been there for at least two months. 
Magento has been patched pretty regularly through ftp. 
In the log folder this exception appears: https://jpst.it/G4kQ .
I can't figure out the problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the alert stating undefined?

Comment: No. It's in the italian translation, but it roughly says: An error occurred during the order elaboration. Please contact us or try again later.

Comment: What payment method are you trying to use? Was the error in the log recorder at the same time yes?

Comment: I tried with the bank transfer option, the site offers that and the Paypal one. No error log, only exception file

Comment: Found something similar in an article on the web. Take a look at this : http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/magento-ecommerce/magento-error-creating-orders-unq_sales_flat_invoice_increment_id - Try backing up your Database and doing this locally to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I've also found some topics and the problems was indeed the duplication of the primary key in the eav table in the db. I'll give it a look.

Comment: I tried to change the values of last_increment_id in the eav_entity_store table with no success. I don't understand though why I get the same exception 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-20150049' for key 'UNQ_MG_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID''. 1-20150049 was the last_increment_id that I changed, so it should not be there. I tried flushing the cache but that didn't lead to any variation.